# Create sparse matrix that stores only the row and column indices of a matrix using C

Tags: c, linear-algebra

I have a (2 x 4) binary matrix A and I want to replace this matrix by a (2*scale x 4*scale) binary matrix B such that element 1 in matrix A is replaced by (scale x scale) identity matrix and element 0 is replaced by (scale x scale) zero matrix.

```
matrix A:
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0

matrix B:
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

However I need only the position of 1's in the matrix B, therefore I create a sparse matrix that stores only the row and column indices of matrix B.

```
0, 0
0, 4
1, 1
1, 5
2, 2
3, 3
```

I am doing this in 2 steps for the below sample code : (1) create matrix B (2) create sparse structure.
This is a sample code where the macros defined is just for this example, in general I work with huge matrices of order 10000 x 10000 or more.

I want to avoid step 1 (i.e creation of matrix B) and directly create the sparse structure to store the row and column indices. Could someone please assist me with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define rowSize         2       //!< row size of matrixA
#define colSize         4       //!< column size of matrixA
#define scalingFactor   2       //!< scaling factor to increase the size of matrixA
#define nonZeros        3       //!< number of 1's in matrixA

//!< struct to hold the position of 1's in matrixB
typedef struct sparseMatrix{
    int row;
    int col;
}sparseMatrix;

int main()
{
    int row, col, idx;
    int matrixA[rowSize][colSize] = {{1,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0}};
    int matrixB[rowSize*scalingFactor][colSize*scalingFactor] = {{0}};
    sparseMatrix matrixC[nonZeros*scalingFactor];

    // check for the element 1 in matrixA and replace it with an identity matrix of size 'scalingFactor'
    for(row = 0; row < rowSize; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < colSize; col++){
            if(matrixA[row][col] == 1){
                for (idx = 0; idx < scalingFactor; idx++){
                    matrixB[(scalingFactor) * row + idx][(scalingFactor) * col + idx ] = 1; // matrixB created
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // create a sparse matrix that stores only position of 1's in matrixB
    idx = 0;
    for(row = 0; row < rowSize*scalingFactor; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < colSize*scalingFactor; col++){
            if(matrixB[row][col] == 1){
                matrixC[idx].row = row;
                matrixC[idx].col = col;
                idx++;
            }
        }
    }


    // print the sparse matrix
    for(idx = 0; idx < nonZeros*scalingFactor; idx++){
            printf("%d, %d\n",matrixC[idx].row, matrixC[idx].col);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Scan `A`. When a 1 isg found in `A`, use a loop to append several pairs of indices to `C`. For a 1 at r, c in `A`, append indices r•scale+i, c•scale+i to `C`, where i iterates from 0 to scale−1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could integrate your second `for` loop inside the first. Therefore, instead of creating the matrix `B` you would directly save its indexes:

```
int i = 0; // variable to save matrixC current index

// check for the element 1 in matrixA and replace it with an identity matrix of size 'scalingFactor'
for (row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
    for (idx = 0; idx < scalingFactor; idx++) {
        for (col = 0; col < colSize; col++) {
            if (matrixA[row][col] == 1) {
                // instead of creating a temporary dense matrix,
                // just save its indexes:
                matrixD[i].row = row * scalingFactor + idx;
                matrixD[i].col = col * scalingFactor + idx;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried this and the output is not in the expected order. `{0, 0}
{1, 1}
{0, 4}
{1, 5}
{2, 2}
{3, 3}`  I have to further sort them based on row and column indices to get: `{0, 0}
{0, 4}
{1, 1}
{1, 5}
{2, 2}
{3, 3}`

Comment: Indeed. You did not specify order was important in your problem. Let me see how I can change data (later today).

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit. Changing the nesting order of the loops should give the expected order.

Comment: Not at all @Bob__. That's the purpose of SO! Thanks for the contribution :)